# Multilingual website - Get specific url part and use this to change the url - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multilingual

I am currently working on a navigation bar with a button that let's you change the language of the page.

First of all, I have two subdirectories for each language version of the website:

```
[...]/en/*.html
[...]/nl/*.html
```

*With *.html standing for every page in that subdirectory*

I'm using the same navigation bar on every page so my question is:
**How can I swap the middle part of the url using jquery/js?**

*If it's not possible with Jquery/js, how can I accomplish this without Jquery/js?*

Currently I only have the url stored in a variable to use it:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

which outputs `/en/home.html` (for example)

Easiest way, I think, is to get the /en/ part from the variable, store it another variable and swap the current part with the other language. I know there are a lot of similar questions to this out there, but I can't seem to find an answer to tweak for my usage.

**Code requirements:**
- Needs to check if it's on the En or Nl version.
- Change the url to the other directory with keeping the *.html intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep your current structure you can just check if current path is NL or EN and switch for the other one like this:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; //Your page path
var page = pathname.slice(4); //The page name

if (pathname.indexOf("/nl/") >= 0){ //if current page is NL send to EN
    window.location.href = '../en/'+page;
}
else{ //if current page is NOT NL send to NL
    window.location.href = '../nl/'+page;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but could you explain the `pathname.slice(4)`? so I can understand for further usage. (I know about the `.slice()`, but what about the 4 inside?)

Comment: Basically `.slice()` removes the _x_ amount of characters of a string from the start. In this case _4_. Which means the variable `page` is only the page name without the `/en/` or `/nl/` after I `pathname.slice(4)`;`

Comment: Actually pretty obvious and I found the explanation on the API documentation. I really should consider using it more.